# Can you enable a user to transfer in-app purchases to another App?

Tags: in-app-purchase

I'm thinking about creating episodic app. So the first one will be "Episode 1", 2 , 3 etc

The user can make an inapp purchase in any of them, but what I was wondering if I wanted, is there a way I can transfer a purchase someone made in one episode to the next one? assuming every episode is its own separate app?

Comment: What are you talking about? iPhone apps? Android apps? Facebook apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this blog post by Shaun Ervine on a convenience utility to access the iOS Keychain. This allows you to share small pieces of data between apps in a similar style to NSUserDefaults, probably just the right thing for your In-App purchases: http://shaune.com.au/ios-keychain-sharing-data-between-apps/